# Specify output format of DataContractJsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

For the project at hand I have to use `DataContractJsonSerializer` for serialization and have to generate a specific output based on the member's values.

My class looks similar to this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string foo;
  public string bar;

  public MyClass(string f, string b = "")
  {
    this.foo = f;
    this.bar = b;
  }
}
```

Now serialization of a list like

```
var list = new List<MyClass>
{
  new MyClass("foo", "bar"),
  new MyClass("foo1"),
  new MyClass("foo2", "bar2")
};
```

should look like this

```
[{"foo": "bar"}, "foo1", {"foo2": "bar2"}]
```

or - better yet - escaped and as a `string`:

```
"[{\"foo\": \"bar\"}, \"foo1\", {\"foo2\": \"bar2\"}]"
```

- A mixture of strings and objects. How could I achieve this?

I tried to override the `ToString()` method and serializing the corresponding strings resulting in unnecessarily escaped symbols, e.g. `bar2` could be `m/s` and was escaped as `m\\/s` which could not be deserialized correctly on the web server.

Finally, I just need to serialize to this format.  There is no need to deserialize this format with `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

Comment: I believe there is no way to do this purely with `DataContractJsonSerializer` because it shares a code base with `DataContractSerializer` for serializing [data contract types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/types-supported-by-the-data-contract-serializer) and thus doesn't provide access to the underlying serialized format (JSON or XML).

Comment: This would be easy to do if you switched to [tag:json.net].  Alternatively, you could call [`JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/types-supported-by-the-data-contract-serializer) and manually serialize your own JSON output following the rules given in [Mapping Between JSON and XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/mapping-between-json-and-xml).

Comment: I just need to serialize to this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would like to do is to conditionally replace instances of `MyClass` with a [serialization surrogate](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/09/13/wcf-extensibility-serialization-surrogates/) that is a `string` or a dictionary, however using a primitive as a surrogate is not supported by data contract serialization, as explained [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521035/datacontractjsonserializer-doesnt-work-with-idatacontractsurrogate) by Microsoft.

However, since you only need to serialize and not deserialize, you can get the output you need by manually replacing your `List<MyClass>` with a surrogate  `List<object>` in which instances of `MyClass` are replaced with a string when `bar` is empty, and a `Dictionary<string, string>` otherwise.  Then manually [construct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194418(v=vs.110).aspx) a `DataContractJsonSerializer` with the following values in [`DataContractJsonSerializerSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings(v=vs.110).aspx):

- Set [`KnownTypes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.knowntypes(v=vs.110).aspx) to be a list of the actual types in the surrogate object list.
- Set [`EmitTypeInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.emittypeinformation(v=vs.110).aspx) to [`EmitTypeInformation.Never`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.emittypeinformation(v=vs.110).aspx).  This suppresses inclusion of [type hints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17815772) in the output JSON.
- Set [`UseSimpleDictionaryFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.usesimpledictionaryformat.aspx) to `true`.

(Note that `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings`, `EmitTypeInformation` and  `UseSimpleDictionaryFormat` are all new to .NET 4.5.)

Thus you could define your `MyType` as follows:

```
public interface IHasSerializationSurrogate
{
    object ToSerializationSurrogate();
}

public class MyClass : IHasSerializationSurrogate
{
    public string foo;
    public string bar;

    // If you're not going to mark MyClass with data contract attributes, DataContractJsonSerializer
    // requires a default constructor.  It can be private.
    MyClass() : this("", "") { }

    public MyClass(string f, string b = "")
    {
        this.foo = f;
        this.bar = b;
    }

    public object ToSerializationSurrogate()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bar))
            return foo;
        return new Dictionary<string, string> { { foo, bar } };
    }
}
```

Then introduce the following extension methods:

```
public static partial class DataContractJsonSerializerHelper
{
    public static string SerializeJsonSurrogateCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) where T : IHasSerializationSurrogate
    {
        if (collection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var surrogate = collection.Select(i => i == null ? null : i.ToSerializationSurrogate()).ToList();
        var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
        {
            EmitTypeInformation = EmitTypeInformation.Never,
            KnownTypes = surrogate.Where(s => s != null).Select(s => s.GetType()).Distinct().ToList(),
            UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true,
        };
        return DataContractJsonSerializerHelper.SerializeJson(surrogate, settings);
    }

    public static string SerializeJson<T>(this T obj, DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        var type = obj == null ? typeof(T) : obj.GetType();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type, settings);
        return SerializeJson<T>(obj, serializer);
    }

    public static string SerializeJson<T>(this T obj, DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        serializer = serializer ?? new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj == null ? typeof(T) : obj.GetType());
        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(memory, obj);
            memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(memory))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And serialize your list to JSON manually as follows:

```
var json = list.SerializeJsonSurrogateCollection();
```

With the following result:

```
[{"foo":"bar"},"foo1",null,{"foo2":"bar2"}]
```

If you really need the string to be escaped (why?) you can always serialize the resulting string to JSON *a second time* with `DataContractJsonSerializer` producing a double-serialized result:

```
var jsonOfJson = json.SerializeJson();
```

Resulting in

```
"[{\"foo\":\"bar\"},\"foo1\",{\"foo2\":\"bar2\"}]"
```

Comment: I think this is the right direction. Still, the output I needed is given as `"[foo value]"` if bar is empty and `{"[foo value]" : "[bar value]"}` when it isn't.

Comment: @vonludi - can't believe I missed that.  Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Regarding the "Why escape?" question: I think that I need to escape strings when using them in a httpwebrequest according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510437/use-c-sharp-httpwebrequest-to-send-json-to-web-service/20511017#20511017

Comment: Thank you for your help. This gave me the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize will happen based on name and value combination so your text should be like this
[{"foo": "foo","bar": "bar"},{"foo": "foo1"},{"foo": "foo2","bar": "bar2"}]

Comment: So, are you saying it is not in any way possible to override or implement to get the required output? This would be {[value of foo]: [value of bar]} if there is a non-empty bar and [value of foo] otherwise.